# 3D Matrix (Tensor) Operating On a 1D Vector

Tags: tensor

Say you have a tensor $T$ and the components are represented by a 3 by 3 by 3 matrix. And you want to use that tensor to map a vector $u$ into a new vector $s$, both of which are 3 by 1 column vectors.

How do I know how to convert the 3 by 3 by 3 matrix into a matrix that is compatible with multiplication with my vector? How do I know how to reshape the matrix? Which dimension to collapse?

I know that if I can collapse it somehow into a 3 by 3 by 1 matrix, multiplication with a 3 by 1 vector would yield another 3 by 1 vector (the mapped vector $s$ I think). But I have no intuition on how to perform that step.

Comment: $A_{ijk} b_k = C_{ij}$.  You cannot map a vector into another vector using a third-order tensor.

Comment: Right, okay. That makes sense. But I could then map that 2-D matrix onto a vector to get another vector. Maybe that's what I was thinking. Still not sure how you'd actually perform that contraction to get the 2-D matrix.

Comment: $C_{ij} = A_{ijk} b_k$ is the sum of three matrices; $C_{ij} =  A_{ij}^1 b_1 + A_{ij}^2 b_2 +  A_{ij}^3 b_3$.

Comment: What do you the superscripts on the A denote? The various "pages" of the 3D matrix?

Comment: A $3 \times 3 \times 3$ matrix consists of three $3 \times 3$ matrices. The superscripts are the indices of those matrices.  Consider a multidimensional array  $A(5, 6, 7)$, then $A(:,:,1) = A_{ij}^1$, $A(:,:,2) = A_{ij}^2$ etc.